# Python - creating new list/dict from existing list/dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-3.7

I'm trying to take some JSON data returned from a REST call to another application and return a new list with dicts with the filtered data.  It's not working out all that well and I've been at this for over a week without figuring out a solution.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
if r.status_code == 200:
        data = r.json()
        result = []
        for serv_info in data[0]['responseData']['server']:
            result.append({'ip': serv_info['ip'], 'port': serv_info['port'])
            continue
        return result
```

Comment: What does the `data` object look like? What should the `result` look like?

Comment: Could you further describe the issue you encounter? Could you include a minimum working example to replicate said issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: The problem was a total noob mistake.  Missing right curly bracket closing the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While appending data to result your are missing curly bracket. Also continue after appending data is really not necessary. I hope below code can help you,

```
if r.status_code == 200:
    data = r.json()
    result = []
    for serv_info in data[0]['responseData']['server']:
        result.append({'ip': serv_info['ip'], 'port': serv_info['port']})
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your quick and helpful answers.  After looking at it for a while yesterday with a colleague, he pointed out the not-so-obvious-at-the-time syntax error.  Once again, highly appreciated.

--Philip